# Can anyone help me identify this bike from 2002?

Tags: mountain-bike, europe

I got it as a gift in 2002, I was a kid back then. And it was stolen from me in 2004 and I didn't do anything. I would love to buy the same model now, but I can't remember what it was and unfortunately I only have one blurry photo. I just hope I can find an expert to identify this bike. Thank you very much in advance!
By the way, it had a blue seat with a bird sewed, but I can't remember that very well either, must it been an eagle.
[image]

Comment: What did you like best about it? Was it new when you got it, with "stock" components? Do you remember the specifics of what component brands and level were on it? Shocks, # of gears, etc. If you can identify some of those things, a Bikepedia search would probably turn up a few candidates.  I understand the attachment... Last summer, I finally sold a 1998 model MTB that had given me years of great service and still functioned like new; it was hard to let go of it because it still did great on XC trails even compared to newer bikes.

Comment: The picture looks pretty darn generic. Also, bikes change every year (if only in color; we've got better suspension and less rim brakes since 13 years ago), so good luck tracking one  down.

Comment: Picture is quite generic. However, you might try posting it over on bikeforums.net as there are some IKI (Insanely Knowledgeable Individuals) over there.

Comment: This question is three months old - have you found anything further?   Who bought the bike?  Can you ask them?  Were there any papers like warranty cards that may have had details?  What shop did it come from - do they have sales records still ?

Answer (score 1):

This bike looks like my 1998 Specialized Stumpjumper based on color, setup and my guess that the logo behind your left leg is a Specialized S. That's the best I can given the blurry photo and the mud on the frame.